# Using Methods from Object Maps

Tags: java, class, dictionary

I have taken advice from my previous post and integrated maps, sub-classes, and Boolean variables into my word generator. My issue is now getting the letter objects from the map. I can successfully do .get commands from my map, but I can't run class methods from this. Here are some code snippits.
This is my structure for my Hash Map.

```
    HashMap<String, Object> mapVowel = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<String, Object> mapConsonant = new HashMap<>();
    mapVowel.put("a", a);
    mapConsonant.put("b", b);
    mapConsonant.put("c", c);
    mapConsonant.put("d", d);
    mapVowel.put("e", e);
```

I am trying to use a command to lookup the key for the letter objects, and then get the letter object, and use my superclass Letter to run the addChar method I have to add it to the string. As of now I have a get command.

```
    int firstConsonant = 0 + (int)(Math.random() * 19);
    mapConsonant.get(stringConsonantArray[firstConsonant]
```

So how do I get an object and call a method from it by a map command?

Comment: Consider declaring your maps as `HashMap<String, Letter>`, so that a call to `get` returns a `Letter` object. .

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an interface (or abstract class, see below the snippet), let's say `Letter`, then two classes `Consonant` and `Vowel` that implement/extend that. Now you can create a `Map<String, Letter>` and put all your elements in there. Depending on the use case, the `Letter` interface will have some methods that both classes must implement, so you can call that method from the derived interface

```
interface Letter {}
class Consonant implements Letter {}
class Vowel implements Letter {}
```

For example something like this

```
interface Letter {
    char getLetter();
}
class Consonant implements Letter {
    private char letter;
    @Override
    public char getLetter() {
        return letter;
    }
}
class Vowel implements Letter {
    private char letter;
    @Override
    public char getLetter() {
        return letter;
    }
}
```

Again, depending on the use case it might make sense to create an `abstract class` instead. This abstract class can be extended by the both other classes and can also provide common methods.

```
abstract class Letter {
    char letter;
    char getLetter() {
        return letter;
    }
}
class Consonant extends Letter {
}
class Vowel extends Letter {
}
```

Comment: I think `Letter` should be made abstract and getLetter method can be provided as common method.

Comment: @Pramod Why should it be abstract? There are no other methods.

Comment: This is something of a long answer that doesn't really address the question.

Comment: @matt I'd make it abstract because I wouldn't want the Letter class be instantiated. The vowel and consonant class should be used instead

Comment: @matt I think it addresses the question. The problem arrises only because of the wrongfully used `Map<String, Object>`

Comment: Exactly, the issue is using Map<String, Object> and yet you've written this whole post about creating an interface or abstract class, that aren't relevant. Also, who writes abstract classes that don't have an abstract method.

Comment: @matt Someone who just wants to demonstrate the basics. I think the OP can figure it out from there and can read up further. Anyways, thanks for your feedback, feel free to post a better answer!